# Difference between array.push and array.splice in this scenario

Tags: javascript

I am working with an open source project I wan't to change the line...

```
this.model[this.config.childrenPropertyName].push(child.model);
```

to

```
this.model[this.config.childrenPropertyName].splice(this.model.length, 0, child.model);
```

But it breaks the ordering on the object model (this is a tree implementation). But when I test the two methods in a test harness they seem to preserve the order. I thought that implemented as above they would do EXACTLY the same thing...

NOTE :  This was just a silly coding error on my part and there is no difference between the two as answered correctly below

Comment: I think what you intended for the second line is actually`this.model[this.config.childrenPropertyName].splice(this.model[this.config.childrenPropertyName].length, 0, child.model);`, and then the two would be equivalent.  Otherwise, you are inserting at some random point in `this.model[this.config.childrenPropertyName]`, depending on the length of its parent, which is unrelated to anything else in your statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First line inserts `child.model` as last element of `this.model[this.config.childrenPropertyName]` array.

Second line inserts `child.model` as to some position inside `this.model[this.config.childrenPropertyName]` array.

These lines are identical only when `this.model[this.config.childrenPropertyName].length` equals to `this.model.length`, but first line is much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks mate yeah I just couldn't see the problem, second pair of eyes is always good :-)

Comment: Your final statement "These lines are identical only when `this.model[this.config.childrenPropertyName]` equals to `child.model`..." is wrong as it stands. I think you meant "These lines are identical only when `this.model[this.config.childrenPropertyName].length` equals to `this.model.length`..."  I will edit your response accordingly if I can.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, you are inserting the items at the index of the original array corresponding to the length of the second.

For example: if the original is length 5 and the second is 2, it would become `[old,old,new,new,old,old,old]`.

You'll need to insert at the length of the original array, or a number guaranteed to be higher.

See [Array.prototype.splice() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

That said, the first way is so much cleaner. Why not use it?

Comment: Apologies I made a mistake in my question please check as they are now the same.

Comment: I agree.  `Array.push` is very clean.  Changing to `splice` seems counter-productive.

Comment: I am trying to use splice so I can start sending in a parameter later down the line. I am refactoring.